# ANGULAR RXJS : run two behaviorsubjects, return undefiend

Tags: angular, rxjs

I want to run two behaviorSubject together,

```js
ngOnInit(): void {
  this.getProjects();
  this.getEmployees();
  this.initForm();
  if(this.local_data.action === 'Update') {
  this.filForm();
}
            }


getEmployees() {
  this._employeeService.getAllemployee();
  this.subEmployee$ = this._employeeService.employee$.subscribe(
    (employees) => {
      this.employees = employees.employee;
      this.employees.map((emp) => {
        let obj = {
          display: emp.firstName + ' ' + emp.lastName,
          value: emp.id,
        };
        return obj;

      });
      this.optionsEmployee.push(this.employees);
    }
  );
}



getProjects() {
  this._projectsService.getAllProjects();
  this.subProject$ = this._projectsService.projects$.subscribe((projec) => {
    this.projects = projec.projects;
    this.projects.map((proj) => {
      let obj = { display: proj.projectName, value: proj.id };
      return obj;

    });
    this.optionsProjects.push(this.projects);

  });
}
```

I have two projects and six employees,

the output is :

```js
{ projects: Array(2), totalProjects: 2 }
```

I have the full data in the array,

```js
    { employee: Array(2), totalemployee: 6 }
```

```json
{id: 48, firstName: undefined, lastName: undefined, phone: undefined, wagePerDay: undefined, …}
{id: 50, firstName: undefined, lastName: undefined, phone: undefined, wagePerDay: undefined, …}
```

all undefined,

when I run only the employee, I get all the data,
but when run together its bugged,

tried to set (setTimeOut) , it's worked but not best practices

the service is :

employeeService:

```js
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { BehaviorSubject, Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { BaseURL } from '.';
import { IEmployee } from '../_interfaces/emplyee.interface';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root',
})
export class EmployeesService {
  private employeeArray: IEmployee[] = [];
  private employeeSubject = new BehaviorSubject<{
    employee: IEmployee[];
    totalemployee: number;
  }>({ employee: this.employeeArray, totalemployee: 0 });
  public employee$: Observable<{
    employee: IEmployee[];
    totalemployee: number;
  }>;
  constructor(private httpClient: HttpClient) {
    this.employee$ = this.employeeSubject.asObservable();
  }

  getAllemployee(employeePerPage?: number, currentPage?: number) {
    const queryParams = `?pagesize=${employeePerPage}&page=${currentPage}`;
    return this.httpClient
      .get(`${BaseURL}/employee` + queryParams)
      .pipe(
        map((employee: any) => {
          return {
            employee: employee.result.map((employee: IEmployee) => {
              return {
                id: employee.id,
                firstName: employee.firstName,
                lastName: employee.lastName,
                phone: employee.phone,
                wagePerDay: employee.wagePerDay,
                bankAccount: employee.bankAccount,
                bankBranch: employee.bankBranch,
                createdAt: employee.createdAt,
              };
            }),
            totalemployee: employee.total,
          };
        })
      )
      .subscribe((transformData) => {
        this.employeeArray = transformData.employee;
        this.employeeSubject.next({
          employee: [...this.employeeArray],
          totalemployee: transformData.totalemployee,
        });
      });
  }
}
```

Project service is same technical.

Comment: You will get much more clarity as to what is going on when you clean up your code a bit. Some probs here: (a) you map over array but you return nothing and you ignore the resulting array, (b) you are unnecessarily using side effects `this.externalArray.push(obj);` (c) you removed declarations - hard to tell which BehaviorSubjects you mean, (d) we don't know when the services do - so it is hard to help

Comment: updated my code,

Comment: TBH I don't understand this code and what you want to achieve. I think you might be after a very simple thing which is combining two requests and processing their results, something like `forkJoin({ employees: this._employeeService.getAllemployee(), projects: this._projectService. getAllProjects()}).pipe(map(({ employees, projects }) => {... do your transformations here ... }))`. But then without `.subscribe()` in the service calls. I would bet you don't need all that complexity, BehaviorSubjects and returning of the subscriptions.

Comment: There seems to be a lot wrong with your code on a basic rxjs lvl:  A) Your `getAllEmpoyees` method is currently returning a subscription, so you would never actually see data outside of it. B) all this mapping seems highly unnessesary since most if not all of the fields share common name. 

please try to only supply the part that is interresting for your problem at hand and abstract things away that are unlikely to cause a problem so people can focus on the problem and not a wall of text ;)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.